# spring boot yaml profile names resolution

Tags: spring, spring-boot, yaml

I have multimodule maven project in which I have one common part which I want to share between applications.

In common module I'm defining the configuration for liquibase and db connection. For this I have 2 profiles common-prod and common-dev located in application.yaml.

```
spring:
  profiles: common-prod
  # POSTGRE
  datasource:
    url: ${DATABASE_URL:jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname}
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    username: pguser
    password: pguser
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    properties:
      hibernate.default_schema: public
#LIQUIBASE
liquibase:
  enabled: true
  change-log: /db/changelog/db-changelog-master.xml
  drop-first: false
---
spring:
  profiles: common-dev
  # POSTGRE
  datasource:
    url: ${DATABASE_URL:jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname-dev}
    username: pguserdev
    password: pguserdev
#LIQUIBASE
liquibase:
  enabled: true
  drop-first: true
```

now in web application I want to define some additional properties. But when I include them in application.yaml (in web module) I think it overrides the application.yaml from common module. 
So I need to

1. rename the application.yaml from common to something like application-common.yaml
2. rename the application.yaml in application to something like application-web.yaml

if I rename the common module's yaml file am I able to reference the profiles from within this file? eg something like -Dspring.profiles.active=common-common-prod or I need to separate this profiles to separate yaml files?

If I rename web modules config file to application-web.yaml I must allways include the web profile. I can live with that, but it would be simpler to include the profiles in application.yaml and don't care about command line arguments.

Comment: You should be able to override properties with your application.yml as described in the doc: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html btw I think extension should be *.yml and not *.yaml

Comment: Yes I know about overriding, but I don't want to do that. I just want to use defined profiles.